# A little game using Matrix, code doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

We have a n to n matrix (made of nested lists) whose elements are either "+" or "-". What I need to do is to write something that changes "+" to "-" or "-" to "+" with a X-shaped pattern (i.e itself and diagonal upperleft, upperright, lowerleft, lowerright, example below).

So for example if user input of coordinates (i.e index of list1 + 1 and index of list2 +2) is 2,2 (row,column) the result will be:

```
+ - +    - - -        + - -    - - +
- + - to - - -   or   - - - to - + -
+ - +    - - -        + - -    - - +
```

Or if given coordinate is 1,3 the result will be:

```
+ - +    + - -        + - -    - - +
- + - to - - -   or   - - - to - + -
+ - +    + - +        + - -    - - -
```

My code works mostly fine. But when the coordinates are 1,n(n is matrix width)(the upperrightmost point), it just doesn't change 2,n-1(one to the left and one to the down). In other points there are no issues at all.

That is if given coordinate is 1,3 the result should be(as above):

```
+ - +    + - -        + - -    - - +
- + - to - - -   or   - - - to - + -
+ - +    + - +        + - -    - - -
```

But my code gives:

```
+ - +    + - -        + - -    - - +
- + - to - + -   or   - - - to - - -
+ - +    + - +        + - -    - - -
```

Here is my code. Language is Python 3.8 and a and b are indices (minus 1, as list indices start from 0) of the nested lists I wrote the matrix with.

```
try:
    if matrix[a][b] == "+":
        matrix[a][b] = "-"
    elif matrix[a][b] == "-":
        matrix[a][b] = "+"
    else:
        pass

    if matrix[a-1][b-1] == "+" and (a!=0 and b!=0):
        matrix[a-1][b-1] = "-"
    elif matrix[a-1][b-1] == "-" and (a!=0 and b!=0):
        matrix[a-1][b-1] = "+"
    else:
        pass

    if matrix[a-1][b+1] == "+" and a!=0:
        matrix[a-1][b+1] = "-"
    elif matrix[a-1][b+1] == "-" and a!=0:
        matrix[a-1][b+1] = "+"
    else:
        pass

    if matrix[a+1][b-1] == "+" and b!=0:
        matrix[a+1][b-1] = "-"
    elif matrix[a+1][b-1] == "-" and b!=0:
        matrix[a+1][b-1] = "+"
    else:
        pass

    if matrix[a+1][b+1] == "+":
        matrix[a+1][b+1] = "-"
    elif matrix[a+1][b+1] == "-":
        matrix[a+1][b+1] = "+"
    else:
        pass
except:
    pass
```

Comment: How should this coordinate thing work? I didn't get that...

Comment: Coordinates are the locations of points in the matrix, i.e. a and b in my code. I edited clarified it in my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your all-enveloping try/catch is the issue. Never do that if you don't know what exactly you are catching.

In this case, your code proceeds in the order:

- center
- top left
- top right
- bottom left
- bottom right

But the top left corner is out of bounds, so it throws an `IndexError` and exits. It will only have processed whatever got checked before the faulty one.

Before you try/catch every separate case, try to make sure that a and b in `[0, len(matrix) - 1]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have been able to solve my problem according to what you said.